# Net::HTTP SSL_CTX_set_cipher_list: no cipher match

Tags: ruby, http, ssl, openssl

I'm using ActiveResource to proxy a CRUD endpoint, but getting `no cipher match` errors when trying to connect. I have tried everything from explicitly setting the SSL version, to upgrading my local openssl client to setting the cipher list directly.

I wish I could provide more information, but I know the exception [is raised here](https://github.com/rails/activeresource/blob/master/lib/active_resource/connection.rb#L121) and that it throws a `SSL_CTX_set_cipher_list: no cipher match` error.

Do you know why I'm getting this error and how to fix?

---

Here is the connection information from Chrome:

```
Your connection to domain.com is encrypted with 128-bit encryption.

The connection uses TLS 1.0.

The connection is encrypted using AES_128_CBC, with SHA1 for message authentication and RSA as the key exchange mechanism.

The server does not support the TLS renegotiation extension.
```

---

#### Update

I ran the following command in terminal with openSSL to check the connection:

```
openssl s_client -showcerts -connect stage.example.com:13902
```

Here was the output:

```
CONNECTED(00000003)
140735228511072:error:140773F2:SSL routines:SSL23_GET_SERVER_HELLO:sslv3 alert unexpected message:s23_clnt.c:762:
---
no peer certificate available
---
No client certificate CA names sent
---
SSL handshake has read 7 bytes and written 308 bytes
---
New, (NONE), Cipher is (NONE)
Secure Renegotiation IS NOT supported
Compression: NONE
Expansion: NONE
---
```

Not exactly sure what that means. Chrome can parse the certificate just fine. Is this a bug with OpenSSL?

Comment: It looks like you have a wrong cipher specified in your code, that is a name not understood by openssl. But without access to your code it is not possible to say more. In case you've tried to enforce the cipher used with chrome: you have to use AES128-SHA1 and not AES_128_CBC with openssl.

Comment: *"SSL_CTX_set_cipher_list: no cipher match"* -  be sure you are using a cipher from OpenSSL's [`ciphers(1)`](http://www.openssl.org/docs/apps/ciphers.html). Under OpenSSL, `AES_128_CBC` is `AES128-SHA`. A string might look like `"AES256-SHA:AES128-SHA"`.